# Bootstrap row resize event

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to resize 2 columns in a row. 
The first column is the tallest and the other columns need to expand to the same height.

[image: one row, 3 columns]

i tested the following but it doesnt work

```
<div class="row" id="top-row">....

$('#top-row').on('resize', function() { /*col-2,3 height = col-1 height*/ });
```

But the function doesnt work.

Comment: `on('resize')` event works on `window` object only.

Comment: What do you think of solving this problem with CSS only? `display: table-cell` could do it perfectly.

Comment: you could add a min height

Comment: @AlexTodef in CSS. `display: table-cell` to the columns and `display: table` to the row?

Comment: @nagazi to the column. Apply `display: table-row' to row if needed. I can create jsFiddle for you if you provide me your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        block 1 
    </div>          
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        block 2             
    </div>      
    <div class="col-xs-4">
            block 3 
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(function() {
   var $paragraphs = $('#top-row .col-xs-4'),
    heights = [];
    $paragraphs.each(function() {
       heights.push($(this).height());
    });
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(this, heights);
    $paragraphs.height(maxHeight);
});
```

this will take the height of longest block and will apply to all